# Cannot create unit tests in VS 2015

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

When I create a new test method or a new test class in my solution, using VS 2015, I cannot see it on the Test Explorer even after rebuild. And if I right-click the method and run/debug nothing happens.

Then, if I open the solution in VS2013, everything is there and working great.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Ditto here.  Tests were running fine in VS2015, and now, suddenly they aren't discovered in the "Test Explorer" window, even after a total rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I realized today that in order to fix this issue, I had to "unload" a shared project I have in my solution.

I have no idea why shared projects are giving me such headaches after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015. It seems compilation does take place either if it is a new test case or any new code. I can't start click once deployment wizard and some other things....

But, to workaround this specific problem, this is a way to go.

Comment: Please elaborate on how to "unload" a shared project.

Comment: Hi @PéturIngiEgilsson. As far as I remember, right-click the shared project on solution explorer and select "unload project".

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the platform from, say "Any CPU" to x86 or x64.  Also, verify the test project is set to build in Build.Configuration Manager.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not produced any result. I found a workaround in my reply. Thanks.

Comment: That did not help me.